# Implement vibrancy effect on NSTextField

Tags: swift, blur, uivibrancyeffect

How can I implement vibrancy effect on `NSTextField`
I added an `NSVisualEffectView` with interface builder and try to use `NSAppearance` to add vibrancy to the label

```
var varLabel = NSTextField()
varLabel.stringValue = "Some"
varLabel.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .vibrantLight)
```

[image]

Comment: What does the doc say you should do if you look under `vibrantLight`?

Comment: “available only in visual effect views” :( do you have other option?

Answer (score 0):

1. Override `allowsVibrancy`.

#### Objective-C

```objectivec
@interface VibrancyTextField : NSTextField
@end

@implementation VibrancyTextField

- (BOOL)allowsVibrancy {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

#### Swift

```
class VibrancyTextField: NSTextField {
    override var allowsVibrancy {
        return true
    }
}
```

2. Use textColor as [Standard Colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/standard_colors?language=objc). Other colors like RGB or Default Label Color won't work.

#### Objective-C

```objectivec
VibrancyTextField *testField = [VibrancyTextField new];
testField.stringValue = @"Hello ████████████████████";
testField.textColor = NSColor.systemGrayColor;
[testField release];
```

#### Swift

```swift
let testField = VibrancyTextField()
testField.stringValue = "Hello ████████████████████"
testField.textColor = .systemGrayColor
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlVBc.jpg)